# Alternate for openTempFile in haskell

Tags: haskell, hugs

Actually i am working on winhugs and it does not support openTempFile function and i want to use it.How to do it?
I want to do something like :

(tempName, tempHandle) <- openTempFile "." "temp"

But getting error in winhugs that "Undefined variable "openTempFile".
Plz help.

Comment: openTempFile lives in the System.IO module, so you will have to import it first.

Comment: ya ..i 9 that it is in System.IO..but i think winhugs does not support it.So i want a alternate to it

Comment: Please do not change the question completely after it has been posted the first time.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to import `System.IO` first.

```
import System.IO

main = do
  (tempName, tempHandle) <- openTempFile "." "temp"
   ...
```

Edit, since `openTempFile` [doesn't appear to be supported by hugs](http://markmail.org/message/subfsy45bw5pu43z#query%3a+page:1+mid%3akg4hk7jumfso5qqw+state%3aresults) (It should though, it's in the standard IIRC) you have two choices, [use a library using the FFI](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/temporary-1.1.2.3/docs/System-IO-Temp.html) to just hack around it or just switch to GHC.

Comment: And that it's in `System.IO` is something [Hoogle tells you](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=openTempfile).

Comment: I had imported it.But winhugs does not support this function

Comment: @user3001932 Updated, TLDR you're going to have to hack around it or switch to GHC. I suggest the later, or use a library which I just dug up :)

Answer (score 0):

`intercalate x xs` is equivalent to `concat $ intersperse x xs`.

If hugs doesn't have `intersperse` either, one possible definition would be

```
intersperse' v (x:y:xs) = x : v : intersperse' v (y:xs)
intersperse' _ xs = xs
```

Comment: Ok, I swear this was a different question 5 minutes ago.

Comment: He edited it and completely changed it.. which was a bit annoying :(